# Can JsLint be integrated into xCode?

Tags: javascript, xcode, jslint, autocorrect

I'm editing some Javascript files using XCode's editor (I know, you want to ask me why, but bear with me here), and I'd like to have lint run on my edits, regularly.

I don't have a real preference - it might be every time the file saves, or on each edit, or, worst case scenario, automatically when I hit the build or run button.

Can a setup along these lines be put together? Any pointers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the jslint command line utility (installed as a ruby gem) and add a pre-action to your build scheme.
You already have ruby and rubygems installed on Mac OS X, so just

`(sudo) gem install jslint`

Then create a pre-action to run

`jslint path/to/javascript/file.js`

[Source code for the jslint rubygem](https://github.com/geraud/jslint)

Comment: This works as a wort-case scenario; ideally, though, I'd like to have my code checked and highlighted for potential errors as I write it.

Comment: do you absolutely have to use xcode? there is a javascript textmate bundle that has jslint built it. It runs automatically when you save the file and you can run it with a keyboard shortcut as well.