# Validate javascript syntax on xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode4, cordova

Is there any way to get compilation or validation errors on javascript/phonegap based projects for xcode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you could integrate jslint with your xcode build like described in this question: [Can JsLint be integrated into xCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986815/can-jslint-be-integrated-into-xcode)

It would alert you to common errors and "bad" code.

Comment: thanks, but that thread does not give a solution to integrating jslint to xcode...

Comment: yes it does, like it says create a pre action to run :jslint path/to/javascript/file.js